# How would I split the contents of an array with a whitespace?

Tags: spring

0

I have an assignment which asks for everything I have in the code below. That all works fine - I just need to calculate any monthly hours over 160 hours to be paid at 1.5 times the normal hourly rate. My math seems sound and calculates fine:

((hours - 160) * overtime) + (160 * hourlyRate)

But I dont know if I'm putting this if statement in the right method or if it even should be an if statement. My increase/decreasePay methods are working prior to this and they need to stay. I removed some things so it's easier to read.

```
HourlyWorker Class:

public class HourlyWorker extends Employee
{
private int hours;
private double hourlyRate;
private double monthlyPay;
private double overtime = (1.5 * hourlyRate);

public HourlyWorker(String last, String first, String ID, double rate)
{
   super(last, first, ID);
   hourlyRate = rate;
}

public void setHours(int hours)
{
   this.hours = hours;
}

public int getHours()
{
   return hours;
}

public void setHourlyRate(double rate)
{
   this.hourlyRate = rate;
}

public double getHourlyRate()
{
   return hourlyRate;
}


public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   if (hours > 160)
   {
      monthlyPay = ((hours - 160) * overtime) + (160 * hourlyRate);
   }
   else 
   {
      monthlyPay = hourlyRate * hours;
   }
   return monthlyPay;
}

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   hourlyRate *= 1 + percentage / 100;
}

public void decreasePay(double percentage)
{
   hourlyRate *= 1 - percentage / 100;
}

}
What I'm testing with:

public class TestEmployee2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   Employee [] staff = new Employee[3];
      HourlyWorker hw1 = new HourlyWorker("Bee", "Busy", "BB1265", 10);
       
      hw1.setHours(200);    
      staff[0] = hw1;

   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());
   staff[0].increasePay(10);
   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());
}
}
```

Output is:
1600 (initial monthly rate, with 40 overtime hours and 160 regular hours)
1760 (10% increase to the monthlyPay)

Should be:
2006
2206.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) will do the trick.
go over the list of artists you have a split each row to artist/genre.

```
for (String artist : artists) {
    String[] split = artist.split(" ");
    // add some data validation to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
    String name = split[0];
    String genre = split[1];
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this method?

Comment: this methods splits a string into two, you can use it after you have the string for artist/genre string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Files.readAllLines(myPath)` to read from File.

If you are familiar with Streams from Java 8 you can use Streams on read Lines from File.
Using `.stream()` and collecting them in a format you want. Either as list or joining them to a single String.